# Submitscore to unlock Achievments at Google play store in LIBGDX android game crash app

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am facing so many problems with Google play game services using in my libgdx game. uptill now I have solved sign in issues. Now when I submit scores at achievements to unlock them my android app crashes. 
I have used debugging android app.

```
 03-09 14:47:02.213: D/GameHelper(8003): GameHelper: onConnected: connected!
03-09 14:47:02.213: D/GameHelper(8003): GameHelper: succeedSignIn
03-09 14:47:02.213: D/GameHelper(8003): GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in SUCCESS
03-09 14:47:02.213: I/Game Helper(8003): Sign in succeeded
03-09 14:47:05.090: I/my Spash Screen(8003): constructor called
```

after this on my game screen I simply called this on GameOver

```
if ((GameObject.actionResolver.getSignedInGPGS())) {

                GameObject.actionResolver.submitScoreGPGS(20);

    if (AssetLoader.getHighScore() >= 100) GameObject.actionResolver.unlockAchievementGPGS("Ab...........");
```

At this point my app crash and dubugging just take me to the

```
 ....    } finally {
                    sGLThreadManager.threadExiting(this);
                } // this is in GL surface view class
```

One more thing is that  I give empty method in  Androidlauncher  Class for submit score

```
@Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Post your stack trace?

Comment: @ Hermith I got this in debugging ' Dalvik[localhost:8600] 
 Thread [main] (Running) 
 Thread [Binder_1] (Running) 
 Thread [Binder_2] (Running) 
 Thread [GAThread] (Running) 
 Thread [GLThread 1374] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
  GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() line: 1243 
 Thread [disconnect check] (Running) 
'

Comment: I see a `NullPointerException` there. Use the debugger and step through your code to check where exactly the exception occurs and which variable is `null`.

Comment: I dont understand it. My logcat says that sign in succeed. I can See sign in pop up and my own email address pop up then. But When i Just call .actionResolver.getSignedInGPGS())) {         My app is crashing without even going furher.

Comment: @AimanBatul As already mentioned bye noone. Use the Debugger.